# What does "throw somebody into a fervor" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean that possibly makes the White House angry?

"If the yuan was allowed to free float, it would easily fall below seven, making Chinese exports cheap again, but possibly **throwing the White House into a fervor**"

source: https://www.forbes.com/sites/kenrapoza/2017/02/07/why-chinas-central-bank-is-losing-money/#419c3c717e1f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be **thrown into** {a fervor, a tizzy, a rage, disarray, confusion, etc} means to be  suddenly put into that state by something.